# How to combine multiple lines with xargs

Tags: curl, xargs, parallelism

I have a large input file which contains 30M lines, new lines in `\r\n`. I want to process this file in parallel by sending chunks of 1000 lines (or less, for the remainder of the file) to a REST API with `curl`.

I tried the following:

```
< input.xt tr -d '\r' | xargs -P 8 -r -d '\n' -n 1000 -I {} curl -s -X POST --data-binary '{}' http://...
```

Note that I am stripping the `\r`'s with `tr` from the input first, because `xargs` does not seem to be able to split on multiple characters.

However, that command above still seems to provide exactly one line to the `curl` process, albeit for 8 `curl` processes in parallel (because of the `-P 8` argument).

How can I fix this command such that chunks of 1000 lines are passed to `curl`, while remaining the parallelism?

I understand that those lines will arrive in random order at the REST service, which is fine for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Parallel is built for this:

```
< input.xt parallel -P 8 -d '\r\n' -n 1000 curl -s -X POST --data-binary '{}' http://...
```

If you want to keep the \r\n, use `--pipe`. This defaults to passing chunks of ~1 MB:

```
< input.xt parallel -P 8 --pipe curl -s -X POST --data-binary @- http://...
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know `parallel`. Seems to do exactly what I need, thank you! There is one problem, but I am not sure it is related to `parallel`. Should it have been `--data-binary \'{}\'` to make sure that special characters (such as a space, a quote, `&`, ...) are treated well. Or is there a way to pipe the data into `curl` instead? I believe the latter will not suffer from any side effects of special characters.

Comment: Also, I have another problem. The newline of the lines in each chunk seems to get erased. All the lines seems to be interleaved with a space. Is there a way to keep the newlines? Also, special characters seems to be escaped. Maybe both are side-effects of the problem in my first comment?

Comment: I think I found it: `< input.xt parallel -P 8 -d '\r\n' -n 1000 --pipe curl -s -X POST --data-binary @- http://...`

This seems to work in some simple tests. I'll do more tests and let you know or accept the answer when it seems fine.

Comment: The `--pipe` solution works fine, except one minor detail. It seems that `parallel` is adding newlines for each line. So now, we get `\n\r\n` at the end of each line in a chunk, with the first `\n` being the one introduced by `parallel`. Is there a way to disable that as well? It's no biggy, as the REST API can work around that, but it's giving warnings for empty lines.

Comment: I saw there is the `--rrs` option, but then we are left with one single `\n`, while the service ideally is given `\r\n`, as per initial big input file.

Comment: `--pipe` is not adding the `\n`.  You can verify that by piping binary data into GNU Parallel and check the output: `seq 10000000 | gzip -1 | parallel --pipe -k cat | md5sum` is equal to `seq 10000000 | gzip -1 | md5sum`. In other words: Binary input is not changed by GNU Parallel. `--rrs` is not useful for you.

Comment: I'll investigate... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`-I {}` and `-n` are incompatible. `-n n` tells `xargs` to pass `n` arguments to the command and `-I {}` gets one argument and each occurrence of `{}` is replace by it.

If I understand correctly, you want each invocation of `curl` to have *one* argument made up of 1000 lines passed to its `--data-binary`. So maybe:

```
<input.txt awk '{print}; NR % 1000 == 0 {printf "\0"}' |
  xargs -r0 -P8 -I {} curl -s -X POST --data-binary {} http://...
```

That inserts a NUL after every 1000th line (including their CRLF delimiters), and `xargs -r0` splits on those.

I doubt the maintainer of the website will appreciate you sending so many requests. Also note that the output of the parallel `curl`s will possibly end up badly interleaved.

Also note that the size of a single argument can't be bigger than 128KiB on Linux.

Comment: Should it be `NR%1000`? When I do that, I get `xargs: argument line too long`. Note that I also get that when I replace `1000` with `5` for example.

Comment: @FrazierThien, yes sorry, I meant `NR % 1000 == 0`. If any chunk of 1000 (or 5) lines is larger than `128KiB`, that won't work if on Linux, as I said.

Comment: Okay, I understand that now. It works indeed for smaller arguments. Thanks you very much.